# grouping users from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

i have a table like this

```
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| id     | user_id  | preference_id|Sub_Preference_Id |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
|  15145 | 55       |    2         |      7           |
|  15146 | 56       |    2         |      7           |
|  15148 | 58       |    3         |      10          |
|  15150 | 52       |    3         |      12          |
|  15314 | 59       |    1         |      1           |
|  15315 | 60       |    3         |      12          |
|  15316 | 57       |    3         |      12          |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

i want to first group member based on same preference_id, then in that particular same preference_id again i want to group same Sub_Preference_Id.

means ,i want a groups like this :

```
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| id     | user_id  | preference_id|Sub_Preference_Id |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
|  15145 | 55       |    2         |      7           |
|  15146 | 56       |    2         |      7           |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+

+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| id     | user_id  | preference_id|Sub_Preference_Id |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
|  15150 | 52       |    3         |      12          |
|  15315 | 60       |    3         |      12          |
|  15316 | 57       |    3         |      12          |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+

+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| id     | user_id  | preference_id|Sub_Preference_Id |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
|  15314 | 59       |    1         |      1           |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+

+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| id     | user_id  | preference_id|Sub_Preference_Id |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
|  15148 | 58       |    3         |      10          |
+--------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

now i am done like this :

```
$preference_idss = array('1','2','3','4','5','6');

foreach ($preference_idss as $preference_ids) {

    $query ="SELECT * FROM gic_user_preference where preference_id='$preference_ids'";

    $result_preferencea = mysqli_query($createCon->connect(), $query);

    while ($result_preference2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_preferencea)) {

        $groupedData[$result_preference2['sub_preference_id']][] = $result_preference2;
    }

}
```

but i failed ?

any idea how to select data by using select queries, not using php foreach,array etc ?

Comment: use group by  preference_id,Sub_Preference_Id  ?

Comment: You can't receive multi level array by one query to MySql. You can only order the result. I think your approach is correct

Comment: We call that 'ordering', not 'grouping' - which has a particular meaning in SQL.

Comment: ok ok .. sorry strawberry

Answer (score 1):

Using PDO:

```
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($preference_ids), '?'));
$select = <<<SQL
    SELECT * 
    FROM gic_user_preference 
    WHERE preference_id IN ($in)
    GROUP BY preference_id, Sub_Preference_Id;
SQL;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($select);
$statement->execute($preference_ids);
```

Using MySQLi

```
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($preference_ids), '?'));
$select = <<<SQL
    SELECT * 
    FROM gic_user_preference 
    WHERE preference_id IN ($in)
    GROUP BY preference_id, Sub_Preference_Id;
SQL;
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($select);
$statement->bind_param(str_repeat('i', count($preference_ids)), ...$preference_ids);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
```

When you want to search for multiple values on a single field you use 'in' not equals.  Also you need to protect against sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything. Just loop over every record and create an array based on preference ID's and subPreferenceID's:

For example:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM gic_user_preference order by preference_id, sub_preference_id";

$result_preferencea = mysqli_query($createCon->connect(), $query);
$groupedData = [];

while ($result_preference2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_preferencea)) {
    $prefId = $result_preference2["preference_id"];
    $subPrefId = $result_preference2["sub_preference_id"];
    if(!isset($groupedData[$prefId])) $groupedData[$prefId] = [];
    $groupedData[$prefId][$subPrefId] = $result_preference2;
}
```

Comment: when i var_dump the data it's showing the error like this :<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: Sub_Preference_Id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\gic001\admin\index.php</b> on line <b>113</b><br />

Comment: change `Sub_Preference_Id` to `sub_preference_id`. Your table and code doesn't match each other in the question.

Comment: changed , but now only get 4 records :

Comment: yes because there are 4 groups. under those you get the subgroups.

Comment: "under those you get the subgroups " how to get those sub groups . can you help me ..please . i didn't get your point

Comment: what does var_dump($groupedData) say?

Comment: array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "23"
      ["user_id"]=>
      string(2) "59"
      ["preference_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["sub_preference_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }

like this 4 datas

Comment: the first index shows the group id which is 1, the second index shows the subgroup id which is also 1, and it contains the row that user 59 with the id 23. There must be more if there are more records in the database.